# Playing video in media player blackberry

Tags: blackberry

I am having problem in playing videos in media player using the direct URL in blackberry. guide me to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:
http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Playing-Audio-in-Your-Application/ta-p/446826

There are a lot more tutorials in RIM's knowledge base.